# Dataframe modify customer number of occurrences of duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table as follows

```
dat <- structure(list(id = 1:7, group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

  id group value
1  1     1     0
2  2     1     0
3  3     1     0
4  4     2     0
5  5     2     0
6  6     2     0
7  7     3     0
8  8     3     0
```

I have to set the "value" to 1 on the last n number of duplicates of "group", column, for example, if n is 2

```
id    |      group  |   value
------+-------------+----------
 1    |        1    |     0
 2    |        1    |     1     
 3    |        1    |     1
 4    |        2    |     0
 5    |        2    |     1
 6    |        2    |     1
 7    |        3    |     1
 8    |        3    |     1
```

I tried this to set the last duplicate to 1 using this code

```
df['value']  <- with(df, replace(df$value, !duplicated(df$group, fromLast = TRUE), 1))
```

Is there a way to modify it to custom set how many duplicates from last row I want to modify

Comment: I don't understand whey group `3` gets assigned to `1`.  Can you explain that?

Comment: My bad, modified it to reflect the intention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'group' and specify the 'index' `list` of `replace` with the the `tail` or `row_number()` for replacing values

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 2
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(value = replace(value, tail(row_number(), n), 1))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
#     id group value
#  <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     1     1     0
#2     2     1     1
#3     3     1     1
#4     4     2     0
#5     5     2     1
#6     6     2     1
#7     7     3     1
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, tail(.I, 2), group]$V1, value := 1][]
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, we can use `ave`, reverse the sequential index of each `group` and assign 1 to the rows which have index less than `n`.

```
n <- 2
dat$value[with(dat, ave(id, group, FUN = function(x) rev(seq_along(x)))) <= n] <- 1

dat
#  id group value
#1  1     1     0
#2  2     1     1
#3  3     1     1
#4  4     2     0
#5  5     2     1
#6  6     2     1
#7  7     3     1
```